# Reverse/cancel previous jQuery function?

Tags: jquery, html, resize

I have created a function that checks the window width of the browser, and if it is below a designated width to remove a `<br>` tag within an element. However, I want the `<br>` tag to be re-inserted into the element (in the exact same location, in the middle of a string) if the window width goes past the designated width.

Here's my code so far:

```
function removeBreak {
    $('.content h4 br').each(function() {
        $(this).remove();
    }
}
$windowWidth = $(window).width();
$(window).on("load resize", function () {
    if ($windowWidth <= 940) {
        removeBreak();
    }
});
```

Is it possible to modify the resize function to add an "else" statement that cancels or reverses the removeBreak function, thereby adding the `<br>` element back to where it was originally?

Comment: use deattach and attach,  because this would be able to reinserted again, that its?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just hide and show them.

When they are hidden they don't take up any space and won't cause the line to break

```
$(window).on("load resize", function () {
     var $windowWidth = $(window).width();
    $('.content h4 br').toggle($windowWidth > 940);       
});
```

You could also do this more efficiently using css media queries

Comment: Thanks very much charlietftl- your example is what I was after but you are correct in saying that css media queries is more efficient. I hadn't considered that option and will do that.